# xslt 2.0 how to round number? 1.45632 => 1.46

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to round number in xslt 2.0

So for example it will work like this:

```
1.4367 => 1.44
1.3218 => 1.32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [format-number()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-number) function.

Also in In XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0 one can use the `xs:decimal` type to work without loss of precision.

Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <MyTable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(MyValue)"/>
    </MyTable>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the round function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="round(NUMBER_TO_ROUND*100) div 100"/>
```

Comment: You might also like to look at round-half-to-even(), which does "banker's rounding" and allows you to specify the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

You may use format-number(). A possible way to use is as below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(1.45632,'#.00')"/>
```

Note: if you don't want `00` to be there, in case no decimal digit is present then use '#.##' instead.

Comment: **WARNING** The `format-number()`function does "banker's rounding" - same as the `round-half-to-even()` function. `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(0.025, '0.##')"/>` will return `0.02` instead of the `0.03` expected from standard rounding.